# Problem Allowing Memory With Adobe Flash Player in Firefox

Tags: adobe

Whenever I try to play a game, like [Pillage the Village](http://www.kongregate.com/games/XGenStudios/pillage-the-village) using Firefox, a flash window pops up asking me to allocate some memory. The error message is below:

```
There is not enough memory to open this scene. Try to allocate more memory to flash.
```

When I click Allow, Doesn't do anything. Help

Comment: What Ubuntu release are you running?

Comment: Im running ubuntu 14.04

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right click on the game window, and click on Global Settings.

[image]

Once the new browser window opens, navigate to  Global Storage Settings panel, and click on it

[image]

Choose either options, test them to see which one works for you.

[image]

Also you can try doing this.  Right click on the flash game --> settings --> local storage, and set the amount to 10MB, click close.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much Mitch, I owe you a lot. Pillage the Village didnt seem to work, But other games are working fine. Thank you.

Comment: 1 More Thing. Some of the games require 1 Mb. I go in the global storage settings, put it to 1 and even 10. And it still remains at 100 kbs

Comment: Look at the addition in my answer.  These games might need local storage.

Comment: I tried that, But I dont know why, i cant click it, i can use only tab+spacebar, but can't move it to 10 mb, i can only close it or move trough those windows.